# numpy - select by multiple equalities dynamically

Tags: python, numpy

I want to select elements of an array according to multiple conditions but dynamically.

I'd define them as follows:

```
L = [1,2,5]
X = np.random.choice(10, size=(15,))
X[X in L]
```

I know I can do it as `X[(X==1)|(X==2)|(X==5)]` but my question goes for **dynamically** changing L, suppose it is an arbitrary list of integers.

```
index = np.zeros_like(X, dtype=np.bool)
for i in L:
    index[i] = 1
X[index]
```

Is there a better way to perform this?

Comment: Since your first "example" is not working code, I'm not sure what you want to do.  However, I suspect that what you need is to work through a tutorial on NumPy vectorized Operations, and perhaps another on list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get all elements from the input list `X`, which also belong to `L`.

You can use `numpy.isin(...)`:

```py
X[np.isin(X, L)]
```

`np.isin(X, L)` will in essence return array of Booleans for each element of `X` having `True` if it belongs to `L` and  `False` otherwise.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

Comment: If `L` is small enough, `np.in1d` does a loop: `for a in ar2: mask |= (ar1 == a)`, effectively `(X==1)|(X==2)|(X==5)`